# Is there a way to slow down the game environment with gym’s OpenAI?

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-gym

When I render an environment with gym it plays the game so fast that I can’t see what is going on. And it shouldn’t be a problem with the code because I tried a lot of different ones.

Answer (score 2):

Use `time.sleep(.1)` after every render.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually control the frame rate using the 'fps' argument:

`import gym`

`env = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode="rgb_array")`

`gym.utils.play.play(env, fps=8)`

This applies for playing an environment, but not for simulating one.